Laravel Vite + SwiperJs cards effect not displaying properly
I'm trying to get the Swiper card effect to work but with no success. I'm using Laravel + Vite with the core JS of Swiper.
I've followed the quick start guide and installed via NPM the package for Swiper.
After that I've add in app.js the following lines
import Swiper from "swiper";
let swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
    effect: "cards",
    grabCursor: true,
    initialSlide: 2,
    speed: 500,
    loop: true,
    rotate: true,
    mousewheel: {
        invert: false,
    },
});

In my app.css I've added the following lines:

.swiper {
    width: 240px;
    height: 320px;
}

.swiper-slide {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 18px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(1n) {
    background-color: rgb(206, 17, 17);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(3n) {
    background-color: rgb(10, 184, 111);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(4n) {
    background-color: rgb(211, 122, 7);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(5n) {
    background-color: rgb(118, 163, 12);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(6n) {
    background-color: rgb(180, 10, 47);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(7n) {
    background-color: rgb(35, 99, 19);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(8n) {
    background-color: rgb(0, 68, 255);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(9n) {
    background-color: rgb(218, 12, 218);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(10n) {
    background-color: rgb(54, 94, 77);
}

In the end in the HTML I've added the following structure:
          <!-- Swiper -->
          <div class="swiper mySwiper">
              <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
              </div>
          </div>

And this is the end result:
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/assets/32356067/66e96e8d-590b-4f6c-a696-a9bb4375b3ab
I copied ready examples from codepen and they don't seem to work too.
This is what I've got in my Swiper's NPM directory in node_modules.
Am I importing something wrong or what?

I've also checked https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#css-styles and tried to add the styles from there that are related to the cards,  but I have no CSS folder in general in the package.

Do You have any errors in the console? Are the style(s) and script(s) for the swiper loaded?

They are loaded, yes, no errors in the console or what so ever. Logs are clear too :(. I have a few other things loaded that are working. I'm almost 99% sure that the problem is in the things that I'm importing in the JS

You need to import the card effect separately. By default Swiper only exports its core functionality.
Note: Most Swiper examples use the bundle which includes everything.
import Swiper from "swiper";
import { EffectCards } from "swiper/modules";

let swiper = new Swiper( ".swiper", {
  modules: [ EffectCards ],
  effect: "cards",
  grabCursor: true,
  initialSlide: 2,
  speed: 500,
  loop: true,
  rotate: true,
  mousewheel: {
    invert: false,
  },
} );


awesome, thank you. I've tried to import it, but I guess I got the wrong import ^^
